# Overwriting a global variable and using the returned value as an input to the same function at the next iteration (Python)

Tags: python

I'm looking to overwrite a global variable (doesn't seem to be an issue), and use the overwritten/returned value as an input to the same function continuously (using schedule package) on Python3.6

```
import schedule
import time


num = 4
print('Original number:', num)

def do_function(inputnumber):
    global num

    num = inputnumber + 1
    print('input number:', inputnumber)
    print('new number:', num)

    return num

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(do_function, inputnumber=num)
# at every iteration, num should be updated with the new value determined from within the function


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Current Output:

```
Original number: 4
input number: 4
new number: 5
input number: 4
new number: 5
```

Required Output:

```
Original number: 4
input number: 4
new number: 5
input number: 5
new number: 6
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Why bother with the `inputnumber` argument at all? You want it to be equal to `num` every time so just use `num`

Comment: based on the code you shared, the `inputnumber` will always be 4, since it was set once outside the `while` loop.

Comment: Just a question: why declaring `num` as global inside the function when it has been declared outside before?

Comment: @catzilla  - can you elaborate please? Is it possible to include the overwritten num value in the while loop?

Comment: @Philip, I guess it would be possible, but I believe it would defeat the purpose of the `schedule` library - since the scheduler should be set once, and the function should be run based on the schedule set.

Comment: @Philip does it mean it's not useful anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sample code, the `inputnumber` will always stay as `4` since it was passed in the scheduler **once**.

```py
schedule.every(5).seconds.do(do_function, inputnumber=num)
```

the `num` at that time is 4, and it will not update in the `do_function` since the schedule was only called once.

Based on the expected output, it would be better to just use the global `num` variable directly instead of passing it as a parameter.

```py
import schedule
import time


num = 4
print('Original number:', num)

def do_function():
    global num
    
    old_num = num
    num = num + 1
    print('old number:', old_num)
    print('new number:', num)

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(do_function)
# at every iteration, num should be updated with the new value determined from within the function


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because do method is store only num's variable. do method was called only once and when do was called, num's variable was 4. when schedule object calls do_function, it passes 4 not current num variable. You can see that source code:

```
def do(self, job_func: Callable, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Specifies the job_func that should be called every time the
        job runs.
        Any additional arguments are passed on to job_func when
        the job runs.
        :param job_func: The function to be scheduled
        :return: The invoked job instance
        """
        self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs) # <---
        functools.update_wrapper(self.job_func, job_func)
        self._schedule_next_run()
        if self.scheduler is None:
            raise ScheduleError(
                "Unable to a add job to schedule. "
                "Job is not associated with an scheduler"
            )
        self.scheduler.jobs.append(self)
        return self
```

Look at the indicated line. do function passes the function and its parameters to the functools.partial method. If you look at what partial method does their parameters:

```
def partial(func, /, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

it store the parameters in the dictionary.

What you can do is that

1. use @catzilla's solution.
2. If you want to pass parameter, make num list.

   ```
    enter code here
    import schedule
    import time


    num = [4,]
    print('Original number:', num)

    def do_function(inputnumber):
        global num

        num[0] = inputnumber[0] + 1
        print('input number:', inputnumber)
        print('new number:', num)

        return num

    schedule.every(5).seconds.do(do_function, inputnumber=num)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
   ```

But don't forget that every time you change the num's item, it automatically change affect inputNumber. the result of the 2nd solution is something like that:

```
Original number: 4
input number: 5
new number: 5
input number: 6
new number: 6
```